# How to use lodash to filter list from big list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am working on back end thing where i have list of one large data and i have another list which i want to find which it is exist on biiger list or not. If it exist then it should return empty array other wise it shoul return only unique element.
My big list is like this:

```
[ { name: 'Kapil',
    _id: 59ffb40d62d346204e09c0c1,
    tags: [] },
  { name: 'Nitin',
    _id: 59ffb40d62d346204e09c0d9,
    tags: [] },
  { name: 'Rakesh',
    _id: 5a0180b0d76afa5eaa79db05,
    tags: [] },
{much more} ]
```

and my  list which i want to find this in bigger list:

```
[{ name: 'Neelesh',
   _id: 59ffb40d62d346204easdwd9,
   tags: [] },
 { name: 'Rakesh',
  _id: 5a0180b0d76afa5eaa79db05,
  tags: [] }]
```

Then it should return only this as a result :

```
{ name: 'Neelesh',
       _id: 59ffb40d62d346204easdwd9,
       tags: [] }
```

as it does not in big list.
My lodash script is this:

```
_.filter(my_given_list,(item) => (_.find(bigger_list,{name:item.name})))
```

but it does not give my expected result.Where I am doing wrong??

Comment: don't see any property `actor` in list objects

Comment: sorry my mistake.it should be item.name

Comment: Shouldn't it be `!_.find(..`? You want only ones that don't exist correct?

Comment: yeah but it doesnot work..it return the result which is already on bigger list

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/uvnLva1k/

Comment: Thanks man.. i dont know why its not working..but anyways thanks again

Comment: replace _.filter by _.reject

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl mentioned it should be `!_.find(..` to filter items that already in the big list. I ran fiddle with that code and it worked well.

```
var bigList = 
    [ 
      { 
        name: 'Kapil',
        _id: "59ffb40d62d346204e09c0c1",
        tags: [] 
      },
      { 
        name: 'Nitin',
        _id: "59ffb40d62d346204e09c0d9",
        tags: [] 
      },
      { 
        name: 'Rakesh',
        _id: "5a0180b0d76afa5eaa79db05",
        tags: [] 
      }
 ]

var myList = 
    [
      { 
        name: 'Neelesh',
       _id: "59ffb40d62d346204easdwd9",
       tags: [] 
      },
      { 
      name: 'Rakesh',
      _id: "5a0180b0d76afa5eaa79db05",
      tags: [] 
      }
    ]

var result = _.filter( myList,
                      ( item ) => ( !_.find( bigList, { name:item.name } ) )
                     )

console.log( result )
```

Result

```
[[object Object] {
  _id: "59ffb40d62d346204easdwd9",
  name: "Neelesh",
  tags: []
}]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsbin.com/noyepipovu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.differenceBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#differenceBy) (`name` or `_id` in your case) to find items that exist in `myList`, and don't exit in `bigList`:

```js
var bigList = [{"name":"Kapil","_id":"59ffb40d62d346204e09c0c1","tags":[]},{"name":"Nitin","_id":"59ffb40d62d346204e09c0d9","tags":[]},{"name":"Rakesh","_id":"5a0180b0d76afa5eaa79db05","tags":[]}]
var myList = [{"name":"Neelesh","_id":"59ffb40d62d346204easdwd9","tags":[]},{"name":"Rakesh","_id":"5a0180b0d76afa5eaa79db05","tags":[]}]
  
var result = _.differenceBy(myList, bigList, '_id')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```